# how to migate a Akka cluster without stopping service

Tags: akka, opendaylight, akka-cluster, akka-persistence

I started a ODL(opendaylight) cluster with the following akka config:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdWiL.png)

So, the nodes(11.128.83.43, 11.128.83.33, 11.128.83.32) make up a cluster， 11.128.83.43 is member-1, 11.128.83.33 is member-2 and 11.128.83.32 is member-3.  these days I want to expand two nodes(11.128.83.41, 11.128.83.48) into the cluster, so i'm wandering if the akka will allow me to update and reload the config without shutdown the cluster service?

I searched some akka docs, there is no related anwser

Answer (score 2):

The existing nodes do not need to be shutdown: it should be sufficient to configure the new nodes to [use at least one of the existing nodes as a seed node](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster.html#joining).

Comment: but the existing three nodes will be shutdown thesedays,  the worse thing is that I can't reuse the old IPs(11.128.83.43, 11.128.83.33, 11.128.83.32), so I have to move the cluster to somewhere else.

Comment: Are the existing nodes running, or are you looking to setup an all-new cluster?

Comment: Once a node is in the cluster, it's configured seed nodes no longer matter (so there's no need to update the seed nodes for a node that's already in the cluster).

Comment: what if the new node restared ? i think i need to update the akka config to rejoin the cluster because the akka seed nodes are old nodes which are shutdown

Comment: If a node restarts, it will need the new seed nodes.  But updating the seed nodes configured on a node does not force a restart (the updated seed nodes are there for the next start, whenever that may be).

Comment: @zhangmroy can you explain it more clearly?
" but the existing three nodes will be shutdown thesedays, the worse thing is that I can't reuse the old IPs(11.128.83.43, 11.128.83.33, 11.128.83.32), so I have to move the cluster to somewhere else. "